# How to Insert PHP Code in all WordPress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add my own custom PHP script to all Wordpress pages of my blog.

I am not referring to adding PHP onto a single page (which can be done with a plugin).

Essentially, this is what I need to do:

- Add a snippet of code directly to Wordpress script that handles
  display of posts.
- The snippet needs to be able to grab a ID of the post.

Can someone show me the best way to do this?

This is what I need to figure out:

- Which of the Wordpress php files handles the display of the Wordpress
  posts (is it post-template.php by any chance?)
- How to grab the Post ID using PHP? I found the page which says this could be the possible way, is that correct way of getting the Post ID?

  $id = get_the_ID();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for single post, it `single.php` and to get post ID

```
$post = get_post();
$id = $post->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the theme. Very simple themes might use `index.php` for all pages, others use `single.php` for the display of single posts, and there are a lot more possibiites, also secondary templates (template parts) which are included in the primary templates and contain part of the post. Have a look in the theme folder.

Inside all of these, the posts are always inside "the loop". This page has the explanation and some useful examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop 
HTH